# Wordpress permalink with trailing slash give 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the wordpress on this url:

`http://www.website.com/blog/`

If I try to open any post the url only work as:

```
http://www.website.com/blog/%postname%
```

When I try to put trailing slash at the end it give error 404.

```
http://www.website.com/blog/%postname%/
```

This is my .htaccess

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

It was URlScan It was blocking my Urls because some of them contain dots.

example: `http://website.com/blog/test-3.0/style/foo.css`

I opened up the UrlScan.ini file located:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\urlscan\UrlScan.ini
```

And changed **AllowDotInPath=0** to **AllowDotInPath=1**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to regenerate the permalinks and set custom structure in Wordpress settings.

```
http://www.website.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: I can't change URLs easily because the SEO. It was working as : 'http://www.website.com/blog/%postname%/' but today give me 404 to all pages..